# SQL: How do I select only the newest record when selecting multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I want to take this "returned" set of results and turn it into the one below it based on the created date being the youngest (newest) to indicate the most recent addition.

```
PhoneNum    sourcetable      FullName         reference        Task                                         CreatedDate
    0   This is not important   Mr john smith   39161   This is different every time, but has been renamed  16/03/2015 15:01:05
    0   This is not important   Mr john smith   39161   This is different every time, but has been renamed  12/03/2015 16:58:22
    0   This is not important   Mr john smith   39161   This is different every time, but has been renamed  12/03/2015 16:58:25
    0   This is not important   Mr john smith   39161   This is different every time, but has been renamed  10/03/2015 12:29:50
    0   This is not important   Mr john smith   39161   This is different every time, but has been renamed  12/03/2015 14:18:47
    0   This is not important   Mr john smith   39161   This is different every time, but has been renamed  10/03/2015 12:40:21
    1   This is not important   Mr wilson smith 39158   This is different every time, but has been renamed  10/03/2015 12:07:14
    1   This is not important   Mr wilson smith 39158   This is different every time, but has been renamed  10/03/2015 12:07:14
    1   This is not important   Mr wilson smith 39158   This is different every time, but has been renamed  10/03/2015 12:07:13
```

What I need to return:

```
PhoneNum    sourcetable     FullName       reference      Task                                           CreatedDate
0   This is not important   Mr john smith   39161   This is different every time, but has been renamed  12/03/2015 16:58:25
1   This is not important   Mr wilson smith 39158   This is different every time, but has been renamed  10/03/2015 12:07:14
```

What I have so far

```
select distinct d.PhoneNum,d.sourcetable,N.FullName,C.fk_applicationid as ref,t.Subject,t.CreatedDate 
from Dial d
join Database.dbo.DM_PhoneNumbers p on p.PhoneNum1 = d.PhoneNum collate latin1_general_CI_AS
join Database.dbo.DM_PhoneNumbers on p.PhoneNum2 = d.PhoneNum collate latin1_general_CI_AS
join Database.dbo.DM_ClientApplicants C on C.FK_ClientID = P.FK_ApplicationID
join Database.dbo.DM_Names N on c.FK_ClientID = N.FK_ApplicationID
join Database.dbo.Tasks T on T.FK_ApplicationID = c.FK_ApplicationID
where c.FK_ClientID in (39157,39160)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use `GROUP BY` on columns: PhoneNum, FullName, Reference. And the `max` function on CreatedDate column. Then `INNER JOIN` that result to the query you have now. Just for starters.

Comment: order by t.CreatedDate desc should do it

Comment: how did you get the record with date `12/03/2015 16:58:25` for `phnum 0`? your expected output does not match your requirement

Comment: nvm on my other comment, i deleted.  I forgot to scroll properly.

Comment: Also there's a bit of dissonance between your question, and the title. In the title you want oldest records, but in your question you want newest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the rank function to find the old record, This is not tested!! hope this help

```
SELECT * FROM (

    select distinct d.PhoneNum,d.sourcetable,N.FullName,C.fk_applicationid as ref,t.Subject,t.CreatedDate 
    , RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY  N.FullName ORDER BY t.CreatedDate DESC ) AS iRank


    from Dial d
    join Database.dbo.DM_PhoneNumbers p on p.PhoneNum1 = d.PhoneNum collate latin1_general_CI_AS
    join Database.dbo.DM_PhoneNumbers on p.PhoneNum2 = d.PhoneNum collate latin1_general_CI_AS
    join Database.dbo.DM_ClientApplicants C on C.FK_ClientID = P.FK_ApplicationID
    join Database.dbo.DM_Names N on c.FK_ClientID = N.FK_ApplicationID
    join Database.dbo.Tasks T on T.FK_ApplicationID = c.FK_ApplicationID
    where c.FK_ClientID in (39157,39160)

) AS t 
WHERE t.iRank = 1
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REFERENCE ORDER BY CREATEDDATE DESC) AS RN
FROM [TABLE])
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Obviously you can just change your select statement to get the desired columns.

Comment: This is the correct method, but will need to be reworked a little to fit his tables/columns/joins/etc.

Comment: considering you have 4 upvotes It would seem this answer will work for others, however the one that worked for me, is the answer above yours, thank you for the help though.

Comment: It's essentially the same answer, but he did your job :). Happy to help.

Comment: This is a overall better answer.

Answer (score 0):

add "order by" to the end to get the order and "desc" to be newest first

```
ORDER BY t.CreatedDate DESC
```

add group by to the end

add "top " just after select to limit the number of records returned

```
SELECT TOP 1 ...
```

---

OK try again

```
SELECT 
    person.PhoneNum,
    person.sourcetable,
    person.FullName,
    person.ref,

    t.Subject,t.CreatedDate 

FROM Database.dbo.Tasks t
JOIN (
    SELECT d.PhoneNum,d.sourcetable,N.FullName,C.fk_applicationid as ref
    FROM Dial d
    JOIN Database.dbo.DM_PhoneNumbers p on p.PhoneNum1 = d.PhoneNum collate latin1_general_CI_AS
    JOIN Database.dbo.DM_PhoneNumbers on p.PhoneNum2 = d.PhoneNum collate latin1_general_CI_AS
    JOIN Database.dbo.DM_ClientApplicants C on C.FK_ClientID = P.FK_ApplicationID
    JOIN Database.dbo.DM_Names N on c.FK_ClientID = N.FK_ApplicationID

    WHERE c.FK_ClientID in (39157,39160)

) person ON T.FK_ApplicationID = person.ref

ORDER BY t.CreatedDate DESC
```

here, I am selecting the task by newest first and joining to the sub selected people for which there will be one per person

I don't have your db, hope it works or gives you the right steer

Comment: would this work if I am attempting to pull 2 sets of strings for mr john smith and mr wilson? or would it pull just mr wilson/smith?

Comment: change top 1 to top 2 to get 2 records, but will only depend on their created date

Comment: I just attempted this, as I feared it did not pull both people.

Comment: ah you want to group them

Comment: This won't work for what he's trying to do.  He doesn't want the most recent single record ordered by createdate, he wants the most recently created record for each phone number.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change it with the last line I added. Select only the most recent date for each client:

```
select distinct d.PhoneNum,d.sourcetable,N.FullName,C.fk_applicationid as ref,t.Subject,t.CreatedDate 
from Dial d
join Database.dbo.DM_PhoneNumbers p on p.PhoneNum1 = d.PhoneNum collate latin1_general_CI_AS
join Database.dbo.DM_PhoneNumbers on p.PhoneNum2 = d.PhoneNum collate latin1_general_CI_AS
join Database.dbo.DM_ClientApplicants C on C.FK_ClientID = P.FK_ApplicationID
join Database.dbo.DM_Names N on c.FK_ClientID = N.FK_ApplicationID
join Database.dbo.Tasks T on T.FK_ApplicationID = c.FK_ApplicationID
where c.FK_ClientID in (39157,39160)
AND CreatedDate >= ALL (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(CreatedDate) FROM Tasks WHERE PhoneNum = d.PhoneNum)
```

This way you will get all your clients, but only the last added line for each one.